# Silverlight 4 Load Testing with Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate

Tags: c#, silverlight, visual-studio-2012, load-testing, performance-testing

I know that there are similar questions however I have not been able to find what I'm looking for

I have the task to create load tests for a Silverlight 4 application.

*(I'm not a Silverlight developer)*

I'm using the following tools:

- Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate
- Fiddler 2.4.4.5

The way I found to create the tests is using Fiddler to get the HTTP requests made by the Silverlight application and then export them to a Visual Studio Web Test format (*.webtest)

But I'm thinking that this is not the optimal way to do it because there are some actions on the Silverlight application that are not recorded by Fiddler, so I think they are executed on the client side therefore Fiddler cannot detect them, which makes perfect sense, but either way, they do take some time to execute and I have the feeling that my test is not completly reliable because **Fiddler is not grabbing all the actions executed on the Silverlight app**

Also, my test is getting the HTTP request/response made by the application via WCF Services, and that's what Fiddler can detect, so my tests are actually only testing the WCF service calls, **and I think that I'm missing the Silverlight processing time that takes to display the results to the user**

- So is there a better way to create load tests for Silverlight applications??
- or detect when the Silverlight application has been loaded?

I'd rather keep using Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate than a third party tool because the company is already paying the licence, but I could evaluate other tools though...

Comment: I found this link really useful http://blogs.msdn.com/b/slumley/archive/2007/12/30/web-tests-work-at-the-http-layer.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to test the effects of load on the server, then the only thing you need to do is simulate the traffic that goes to the server.  The server can only see these messages - it is not affected by anything else that happens on the client. It is, of course, affected by the timing of the messages...so if something in the client causes the message rate to change, that should be simulated as well.

If your goal is to test the performance of the client (the Silverlight app), then you don't need to load test. The client doesn't know that there are other clients running. It only sees the messages it exchanges with the server. If the performance of the server degrades, this may be reflected in the client app. But you can simulate that by altering the responsiveness of the server. Concurrency and load are not required.  In most cases, all you need is basic math to determine the impact of server-side slowdowns on the client - e.g. if the server response time goes from 2 seconds to 3 seconds, the response time in the client (as seen by the users) will typically degrade by the same amount. There are edge cases where this is not true, but with the right setup, you can easily vary the response times at the server to simulate any possible scenario, including those that would be difficult or impossible to consistently replicate with a load test.

Hope that helps!